# Run Apache on port 81 with SeLinux Off

Tags: apache, selinux

I have done "semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 81" and modified httpd.conf to listen on port 81. After restart httpd service it is not working. but it is working with default port 80.  I have checked my SeLinux and it is in fact disabled. Can some one get me out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you have iptables blocking port 81?

iptables -L